# Regex match apostrophe inside, but not around words, inside a character set

Tags: javascript, regex, diacritics, apostrophe, single-quotes

I'm counting how many times different words appear in a text using Regular Expressions in JavaScript. My problem is when I have quoted words: `'word'` should be counted simply as `word` (without the quotes, otherwise they'll behave as two different words), while `it's` should be counted as a whole word.

`(?<=\w)(')(?=\w)`

This regex can identify apostrophes inside, but not around words. Problem is, I can't use it inside a character set such as `[\w]+`.

`(?<=\w)(')(?=\w)|[\w]+`

Will count `it's a 'miracle' of nature` as 7 words, instead of 5 (`it`, `'`, `s` becoming 3 different words). Also, the third word should be selected simply as `miracle`, and not as `'miracle'`.

To make things even more complicated, I need to capture diacritics too, so I'm using `[A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]` instead of `\w`.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You can simply use `/[^\s]+/g` regex

[image]

```js
const str = `it's a 'miracle' of nature`;
const result = str.match(/[^\s]+/g);

console.log(result.length);
console.log(result);
```

**2)** If you are calculating total number of words in a string then you can also use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) as:

```js
const str = `it's a 'miracle' of nature`;
const result = str.split(/\s+/);

console.log(result.length);
console.log(result);
```

**3)** If you want a word without `quote` at the starting and at the end then you can do as:

```js
const str = `it's a 'miracle' of nature`;
const result = str.match(/[^\s]+/g).map((s) => {
  s = s[0] === "'" ? s.slice(1) : s;
  s = s[s.length - 1] === "'" ? s.slice(0, -1) : s;
  return s;
});

console.log(result.length);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear enough: `'miracle'` should be counted as `miracle` (without the quotes), otherwise they will appear as two different words.

Comment: Still it works. Total count will be `5`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough again! My final objective is to count how many times each word repeat. So no word should appear quoted, otherwise it will become a different word.

Comment: @Rodrigo Then what should be your expected result? You should specify it in the question itself

Comment: `5 ["it's", "a", "miracle", "of", "nature"]` i.e. `miracle` must appear unquoted.

Comment: Edited the question three times now. Thank you.

Comment: @Rodrigo I've added solution `3`. Please have a look

Comment: Yes, it works. But maybe is there a regex-only solution?

Answer (score 1):

You might use an alternation with 2 capture groups, and then check for the values of those groups.

```
(?<!\S)'(\S+)'(?!\S)|(\S+)
```

- `(?<!\S)'` Negative lookbehind, assert a whitespace boundary to the left and match `'`
- `(\S+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `'(?!\S)` Match `'` and assert a whitespace boundary to the right
- `|` Or
- `(\S+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ non whitespace chars

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/me4Plt/1).

```js
const regex = /(?<!\S)'(\S+)'(?!\S)|(\S+)/g;
const s = "it's a 'miracle' of nature";

Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => {
  if (m[1]) console.log(m[1])
  if (m[2]) console.log(m[2])
});
```

Comment: Strange that in regex101.com it includes the apostrophes in `'miracle'`, but not here...

Comment: @Rodrigo It is "matched" but not captured in a group. You can see the captured, and the eventually used values highlighted in green and orange in the regex demo https://regex101.com/r/me4Plt/1

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!